# Nested LINQ query for 2 lists

Tags: c#, xml, linq, subquery

I need to use a nested linq query to lookup matching strings.

I currently have 2 lists with strings, one with all of them, and the other just has 3. I've tried many options, but I just don't understand how these work.

It's probably a really easy mistake, but I'm still new with C# and I'm learning every day.

This is how far I got, but I'm stuck at the looseTracks error.

```
public static void printTracks()
{

    List<string> allTracks = new List<string>(); 
    //This list is filled with strings (Track titles)
    List<string> looseTracks = new List<string>();

    Track track1 = new Track("Smells Like Teen Spirit", "Nirvana", "00:05:02");
    Track track2 = new Track("Come as You Are", "Nirvana", "00:03:38");
    Track track3 = new Track("Lithium", "Nirvana", "00:04:16");
    looseTracks.Add(track1.title);
    looseTracks.Add(track2.title);
    looseTracks.Add(track3.title);

    var query = from tr1 in allTracks
            from tr2 in tr1.looseTracks //Error!
            where tr1.Equals(tr2)
            select tr1;

    foreach (string s in query)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

The error gives me this:

> Error 1   'string' does not contain a definition for 'looseTracks' and no extension method 'looseTracks' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Gebruiker\Desktop\workspace visual studio 2013\Practicum 4\Program.cs  104 45  Practicum 4

I have to use a nested query, but I just don't know how. Is there someone who can help me out?

If I forgot something, or if this doesn't work, please let me know! Thanks in advance!

Comment: tr1 doesn't contain looseTracks. looseTracks is a List.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to do something like.

```
var query = from tr1 in allTracks
            where looseTracks.Contains(tr1.title)
            select tr1;
```

Or just the following in method syntax.

```
var query = allTracks.Where(tr1 => looseTracks.Contains(tr1.title));
```

This is assuming that `allTracks` is a `List<Track>` and `looseTracks` is a `List<string>`.

Comment: It worked, thanks! Sorry for being stupid, still learning how these work

Answer (score 0):

```
//Just imagine this list being filled with 'Track' objects
```

I'm going to imagine it as not being filled with 'Track' objects. You defined it as a list of strings, not a list of tracks.

```
List<Track> allTracks = new List<Track>();
List<Track> looseTracks = new List<Track>();
```

Comment: You're totally right, I'm being dumb. Edited the OP